# Data weave 2.0 help need conversion of XML to corresponding java object

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am using Mule4 Dataweave 2.0 to convert XML to Java Object. Below is the XML and its corresponding JAVA object.

**XML**

```
<student>
  <schools>
    <school>
      <name>FM Elementary</name>
      <city>Dallas</city>
      <state>TX</state>
    </school>
    
    <school>
      <name>FM Middle</name>
      <city>Austin</city>
      <state>TX</state>
    </school>
    
  </schools>
</student>
```

Need to convert to Java object, the java class structure is given below.

**School.java**

```
public class School { 
    public String name;
    public String city;
    public String state;
}
```

**Schools.java**

```
public class Schools { 
    public List<School> school;
}
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student { 
    public Schools schools;
}
```

I can able to convert Upto Student Class but not sure how to parse the Schools and Schools xml tag. Find below data weaver code

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
  schools: payload.body.Student.Schools
} as Object {
    class: "com.application.edu.Student"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is the [MultiValue Selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-selectors#multi_value_selector) `payload.body.Student.*Schools` this will return an array with all the `Schools` and then you can map it

So at the end

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
  schools: payload.body.Student.*Schools
             map ((school) -> school as Object {
               class: "com.application.edu.Student"
             })
} as Object {class: "com.application.edu.Schools"}
```